# Not able to connect to GCM server in iOS app after switching google developer account

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an `iOS` app for integrating with `GCM`.
I have successfully done all the steps and was able to connect to the `GCM` server once.
But then, I changed my google developer account and made a new app in google developer console for using `GCM` with `iOS` and also added new plist file into my xcode project bundle.

Now I am not able to connect to the `GCM` server even once, I have also tried using other device but didn't work at all.

Comment: Have you generate a new API from your new Google Developer account, and added it to your `GGLInstanceID`?

Comment: Do you mean creating new plist configuration file and adding it to the bundle ?? If yes, then i have already done that and added to the bundle.

Comment: You need to make sure to do [this process](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=gcm&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fios%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Try%20Cloud%20Messaging) again with your new `App name`, and get a new `API Server Key` on the download page, more details can be found in [this page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using default APN server with my backend server and left GCM for iOS as it was.
I have read in some blogs that SDK for GCM is not stable yet and it causes some problems frequently.
This happens for when we are implementing login with google plus as well.

So, I would suggest not to use GCM SDK as of now.

Thanks